# How to plot points using m.scatter at certain longitudes and latitudes

Tags: python, matplotlib, indexing, matplotlib-basemap

Say I have an array of indices named `indices` like so:

```
[[1, 34, 56]
 [2, 54, 34]
 [2, 89, 173]
 ...
 [6, 23, 13]]
```

The first element is an arbitrary element. The second and third elements represent longitude and latitude respectively. How can I basically ignore the first element in each index, and take the longitude and latitude value in the index and graph it on a map using `m.scatter`?

Comment: In how far is this question different from your [previous question on that subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511792/scatter-does-not-plot-any-points-on-basemap)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a numpy array you can give the second and third column of the initial array to the map and plot the resultant coodinates with `m.scatter` (if `m` is the Basemap instance).

Let me mention that you probably mixed latitude and longitude in the question and that I suspect that the second column is latitude and the third is longitude.

```
import numpy as np

indices =  np.array([[1, 34, 56],
                     [2, 54, 34],
                     [2, 89, 173],
                     [6, 23, 13] ])

m = Basemap(...)
x,y = m(indices[:,2], indices[:,1])
m.scatter(x,y)
```

Complete example:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

m = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlat=0,urcrnrlat=90,\
            llcrnrlon=0,urcrnrlon=180,resolution='c')

m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()

parallels = np.arange(0.,81,20.)

m.drawparallels(parallels,labels=[False,True,True,False])
meridians = np.arange(0,360.,45.)
m.drawmeridians(meridians,labels=[True,False,False,True])


indices =  np.array([[1, 34, 56],
                     [2, 54, 34],
                     [2, 89, 173],
                     [6, 23, 13] ])

x,y = m(indices[:,2], indices[:,1])
m.scatter(x,y, zorder=5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've instantiated you map object from the Basemap class.

Extract the lat values (x list), the long values (y list), then you can call map.scatter

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter

>>> indices = [[1, 34, 56], [2, 54, 34], [2, 89, 173], [6, 23, 13]]

>>> x = list (map (itemgetter (1), indices))

>>> y = list (map (itemgetter (2), indices))

>>> map.scatter (*map (x, y))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I get an error with the line `map.scatter (map (x, y))`. It says `TypeError: with_transform() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given) `

Comment: ah sorry, i changed the call `map(x, y)` to `*map(x, y)`, i need to unpack the result because map.scatter take 2 positional args

Comment: Hm, another error seems to pop up in the same line. `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` Not so sure what this is about.